# Click on update button in check google service dialog

Tags: android

I use this code to check version of google services:

```
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MapActivity.class));
}else if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING ||
    resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED ||
    resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 1);
    dialog.show();
    setMapFlag(true);
}
```

How can I check if user click update button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to check whether user clicked to update button or not. What really concerns you is detecting google play services' version. User may click to update button, but doesn't update from Google Play, so you should put your checking mechanism to onResume() method.

Comment: I need to recognise that user click on this button to clear flag.

Comment: So the user clicks update button on dialog, but doesn't update Google Play Services case is ok for you?

Comment: In that case I don't think you can detect click event for update button. To detect it, you can show your own dialog, and detect button click.